# LinearLayout after setting Visibility of Ads to Visible the View is being cropped

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout

I am using in my app the following layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                   <FrameLayout
                     android:id="@+id/id2"
                     android:layout_height="200dp"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:background="@color/white" />
                   <pagerslidingtabstrip.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                      android:id="@+id/tabs"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="@dimen/pagertagstrip_height" 
                      android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/ads"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT:** In the FrameLayout with id2 i am inserting another view pager. The pager with id Pager is being controlled from the pagerslidingtabstrip and contains 4 ListViews. I also implemented a part of the parallax header example. So scrolling the Listviews alters the translation of the LinearLayout with id = id1 .

The problem is that after I am enabling the ads (setting the visibility to Visible an inserting a view in the LinearLayout with id = ads) in landscape mode part of the ads does not fit in the screen. But if I scroll to view the ads the ads' View is being cropped. The part that was out of the Screen is not being rendered and I can see only a part of the ads' view. How can I fix this ?

[image: Cropped Ad]

I am getting the ad like the above sample pic (Red color is just from the background)

Comment: I dont under stand why create this type of view hierarchy. Why u need LinearLayout to display ads. They must be View class in your ad provider's SDK. U r using admob ?

Comment: I am using a custom ad provider Sdk and the guidelines say to use a LinearLayout as a parent for the ads(Views). I dont think the problem is from the LinearLayout.

Comment: pls post full xml...

Comment: I posted the full xml and added explanation about the use case. I dont think that this is affecting somehow my problem. I consider that is has to be a problem with the framelayout not altering their height after the ad is set to visible

Comment: check my edited ans...

Answer (score 0):

try this

add `layout_gravity="center_horizontal` ur parent `framelayout`

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
```

hope it works

Comment: This is not working. The Viewpager is not showing any content now and in landscape mode i cant see the ad view either

Comment: Thank you for your time. But sadly, it seems that this is not solving my problem. I think it is something internal from android that it can resize the framelayout. The system lets it be only as is was at the time of the first rendering